# What are all the names, nicknames, epithets, titles, and pronouns used to refer to Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, names

Voldemort is referred to by many titles.  From Tom Riddle to The Dark Lord to [The Second Voice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124541/55866) and many in between.

### What are all the names, nicknames, epithets, titles, and pronouns used to refer to Voldemort in HP canon?

The more inclusive the better!  Bonus points if you list the origin of each name as well.

Comment: Pronouns? You really want "the origin" of "he," "him," and "his"?

Comment: @Kevin - If it improves the answer, yes. Otherwise, stick to more specific ones like "The Second Voice".

Comment: Related: [Are *all* list questions off-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2638/30482#2639)  The argument that has been used against me is that, since the number of Harry Potter books (and movies) is small (well limited) and not expected to grow, that questions bounded by those works are "finite", concrete, and therefore on-topic.

Answer (score 11):

I'll take a stab at starting this off.

#### Proper names

- Tom/Tom Riddle/Tom Marvolo Riddle: name chosen by Voldemort's mother, Merope Gaunt, after his Muggle father, Tom Riddle, and wizard grandfather, Marvolo Gaunt

  > and then she told me he was to be named Tom, for his father, and Marvolo, for *her* father - yes, I know, funny name, isn't it? We wondered whether she came from a circus - and she said the boy's surname was to be Riddle.
  > <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter Thirteen - "The Secret Riddle"</sub>
- Voldemort/Lord Voldemort: name chosen by Voldemort himself

#### Titles and nicknames

- The Dark Lord - used by Death Eaters and Severus Snape; no indication of origin, though likely chosen either by Voldemort himself or first used by a Death Eater
- Master - used by Death Eaters when addressing Voldemort directly; origin as above
- My Lord - see above
- Voldy - [origin in canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/122976/5833) appears to be Peeves at the end of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*
- You-Know-Who - one of the phrases used to refer to Voldemort without saying the name; first used in the very first chapter of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* by an unnamed wizard (a tiny old man), no indication of origin (usage was widespread by the events of the first book)
- He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named - see above

#### Descriptions

- "a/the second voice" - used in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter one before Voldemort and Wormtail are seen by Frank Bryce, no origin since it's purely a description in the text
- "the cold voice" - see above
- "the second man" - see above
- "the voice" - see above

Comment: I meant origin in-universe (who coined the phrase) rather than out-of-universe (first published usage). Still great answer +1.

Comment: @ibid I doubt that's known for most, though I've added the information we do know (Voldemort chose "Lord Voldemort" for himself, Merope Gaunt named him Tom Marvolo Riddle).

Comment: That's why I said bonus points :)

Comment: Your Lordship, Lord Voldything, Lord Thingy, Chief Death Eater, Heir of Slytherin, He Who Could Not Be Named

Comment: @ibid Hm, some of those sound very Dursleyish, though I can't remember exactly which books (would be much more helpful if I had searchable versions of them...).

Comment: GoF1, OotP2, OotP38, DH22, CoS17, PmQWC

Comment: I think his father is more commonly referred to as 'Thomas' and the evil noseless villain is little 'Tom.'